# How to recive broadcast from multipale .net server to android base clients?

Tags: android, asp.net, sockets, broadcastreceiver, broadcasting

I have multiple broadcast server which continuously broadcast the message e.g"I M AVAILABLE AND MY IP ADDRESS IS 192.168.X.XXX"

I can Successfully receive this message with the .net clients.i have made clients with the socket in .net but now what i want is if i have some java base client or android base client who want to get that broadcast message from these .net servers then is it possible?

I have implemented this broadcast and receiver application in .net but for .net server and java or different platform's client i don't know if is it possible and if yes then how because i am new in java.so please can anyone guide me about this.

Following is my server side broadcast code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Broadcst
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        int portnumber = 9050;



            IPEndPoint iep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, portnumber);

            IPEndPoint iep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), portnumber);

            string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hostname);

            sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
            sock.SendTo(data, iep1);
            sock.SendTo(data, iep2);

           // portnumber--;
            sock.Close();
    }
}
```

And to receive broadcasting message from multiple .net server i have made one receiver program as follows..

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class RecvBroadcst
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
     //  int port_no=Convert.ToInt32(sock.RemoteEndPoint);


         int portnumber = 9050;

            sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,portnumber);
            sock.Bind(iep);
            EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");
          // int port_no = Convert.ToInt32(sock.RemoteEndPoint);
            while (true)
            {

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
                string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                                      stringData, ep.ToString());

                //data = new byte[1024];
                //recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
                //stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                //Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                //                      stringData, ep.ToString());

                data = null;
            }
            //portnumber--;


        sock.Close();
    }
}
```

So what i want to do is the Receiver Program i have made in .net as code given above the same thing i want to do for receive broadcast message from multiple .net server in my android device...how can i achieve that?